# Dimension, Linearly Independence, and Span Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the following but find myself stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why does $n$ have to be less than or equal to $m$ where n and m are both integers for the following statement?

> Let $V=\lbrace v_{1}, v_{2}, ... v_{n} \rbrace$ be a set of linearly independent vectors. Also, let $W=\lbrace w_{1}, w_{2}, ... w_{m} \rbrace$ be a set of linearly independent vectors where the
>
> > $span(W)=\lbrace a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n},  
> > b_{1}w_{1}+b_{2}w_{2}+...+b_{m}w_{m}|a_1,a_2,..,a_n,b_1,b_2,...,b_m\in \mathbb{F}\rbrace$
>
> I am assuming a complex field, something easy for this example.

Comment: What do you want to prove ?

Comment: I don't see a question. Just a few statements.

Comment: Are you trying to show that the dimension of a vector space is well defined?

Comment: @Chickenmancer I can do that, but I am trying to show why $m\leq n$ supposing everything else is true. At least for independent sets, I can.

Comment: I don't see where is the "following statement".

Comment: Everything after: n and m are both integers for the following statement?

Comment: It is all correct now. There is a comma that is put in the span(W) that I would like to bring attention to as well.

Comment: What does the comma mean, in this context? Do you mean to say that the elements of the span can have either form?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the statement at the end would be better expressed as $$\operatorname{span}(W)=\bigl\{a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n\mid a_1,...,a_n\in \Bbb F\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{b_1w_1+\cdots+b_mw_m\mid b_1,...,b_m\in \Bbb F\bigr\},$$ meaning, more simply, that $$\operatorname{span}(W)=\operatorname{span}(V)\cup\operatorname{span}(W).$$ What can you then conclude about how $\operatorname{span}(V)$ and $\operatorname{span}(W)$ are related. What about $V$ and $\operatorname{span}(W)$? Can you take it from there?

Comment: Going on from there is the problem I am having. I tried to simplify that equation to the one I posted. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Well, note that we necessarily have $\operatorname{span}(W)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(V)\cup\operatorname{span}(W)$ regardless of our choice of $V$ and $W$ from the overlying vector space. Do you see why that's true? If so, then the important piece of information we're assuming is that $\operatorname{span}(V)\cup\operatorname{span}(W)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(W).$ What does that let us conclude about $\operatorname{span}(V)$ and $\operatorname{span}(W)$?

Comment: So then you get to here $\forall x (x=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n\vee x=b_1w_1+b_2w_2+...+b_mw_m\rightarrow x=c_1w_1+c_2w_2+...+c_mw_m)$. Which I do not see a contradiction yet if $n>m$. I am trying to see where to take the problem from here. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I am honestly trying to answer this problem from this point, but I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: There's no need to try for a contradiction. You're on the right track with your implication. If we know that $x\in\operatorname{span}(V),$ what else can we conclude about $x,$ based on that implication?

Comment: First off, I wanted to let you know I really appreciate you trying to help me out. If $x\in span(V)$, then you would know $\forall a_1, a_2,...,a_m, \exists c_1,c_2,...,c_m : c_1w_1+c_2w_2+...+c_mw_m=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n$, but what could you conclude from there?

Comment: You're right on target! Put another way, you know that for all $x\in V,$ there exist $c_1,...,c_m\in\Bbb F$ such that $x=c_1w_1+\cdots+c_mw_m,$ meaning that $x\in???$

Comment: So $x\in span(W)$. Thus, $v_1\in span(W), v_2\in span(W), ...,$ and $v_n\in span(W)$. You could also know that $c_1v_1\in span(W),c_2v_2\in span(W), ...,$ and $c_nv_n\in span(W)$, and I feel like I am close.

Comment: You are, indeed! Since each $v_k\in\operatorname{span}(W),$ then $V\subseteq\operatorname{span}(W).$ Since $V$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in the $m$-dimensional space $\operatorname{span}(W),$ we're basically done!

Comment: I think I got it! Your help is very much appreciated!